# Limit Displayed Hours on Embedded Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

Is there a way to limit the hours displayed on Google Calendar that will also limit those hours when you embed that calendar on my web site page?

I am using the **Labs Hide Morning and Night** extension which seems to hide the hours when I view my calendar within the Google Calendar site.  When I view the embedded calendar posted to my external web site, the hours are NOT hidden.

Answer (score -1):

This is how far I have come.

Using a CSS to restructure what is visible.

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-select-the-hours-to-display-in-Google-calendar-widget/answer/Kim-Nilsson

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/72628)

Comment: @serenesat True, but the linked answer is my own, which, if changed, will contain my latest progress on this exact matter. If I type the answer here this answer will be outdated, since I will most likely forget to edit it here.

Comment: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/21960)